# Creating Java models in Magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

I installed Magnolia using maven and built and deployed the project successfully. I can also create yaml templates and components.

I would like to create Java models to access external databases and add business logic but cannot find where to create the classes and the documentation is not extensive in this area.

In Netbeans IDE there is no src directory appearing in the project tree. When I created a package and a jave class I get an error in tomcat:

Problem details: Failed to resolve a class property due to a missing class: [newpackage.NewClass]

Where should I create the classes ?

### Update:

I created the classes in a separate Java project and placed a jar in web-inf/lib.
Now I do not get the missing class error but get a rendering cast error

Class:

```
package com.example;
public class NewClass  {

    public String getText() {
       return "Hello Magnolia!";
    }

}
```

YAML:

```
modelClass: com.example.NewClass
```

Template:

```
<h1>${model.getText()}</h1>
```

Error:

RenderException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.NewClass cannot be cast to info.magnolia.rendering.model.RenderingModel

### Update 2:

I modified the class to extend magnolia RenderingModelImpl to this:

```
package com.example;

import info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderingModel;
import info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderingModelImpl;
import info.magnolia.rendering.template.configured.ConfiguredTemplateDefinition;
import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;

public class NewClass extends RenderingModelImpl {

    public NewClass(Node content, ConfiguredTemplateDefinition definition, RenderingModel<?> parent) throws PathNotFoundException, RepositoryException {
        super(content, definition, parent);
    }

    public static String getText() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

Now it does not compile and displays and error for the super statement in the constructor:

```
incompatible types: Node cannot be converted to Content
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working example at [this link](https://github.com/tricode/magnolia-news/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/tricode/magnolia/news/templates/NewsRenderableDefinition.java) on github and modified it from there. The following Java model worked correctly and returned a string I can render:

```
package com.example;

import info.magnolia.rendering.model.RenderingModel;
import info.magnolia.rendering.model.RenderingModelImpl;
import info.magnolia.rendering.template.RenderableDefinition;


import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jcr.Node;



public class NewClass<RD extends RenderableDefinition> extends RenderingModelImpl {

    @Inject
    public NewClass(Node content, RD definition, RenderingModel<?> parent) {
        super(content, definition, parent);

    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        return super.execute();
    }

    public String getName() {
    return "Hello Magnolia!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following documentation page:
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/How+to+use+Magnolia+Maven+archetypes

There you will find information about Maven archetypes and there is a section about how to create a custom java module. After creating you have to add it to your webapp as well.

After edition:
Turns out that you try to inject a model class which you need to extend
RenderingModelImpl in that particular model class you try to assign.

Cheers,

Comment: I tried making the module as a regular jar and also a jar produced by maven archetype magnolia-module, I am still unable to include a custom class in my template, I get the below error and there are no examples on the documentation site: RenderException: java.lang.ClassCastException: package.className cannot be cast to info.magnolia.rendering.model.RenderingModel

Comment: Can you share the class please?

Comment: I edited the original question and added the class.

Comment: You have to extend RenderingModelImpl class to that in runtime it knows that it's an instance of modelClass

Comment: I extended RenderingModelImpl and now receive an error on the constructor. I updated the original question with my code.

Comment: What Magnolia version do you use?

Comment: I am using version 6.1.4 but the error now is in the Netbeans. I used the magnolia-module archetype to build a new project. I created a class that extends RenderingModelImpl and the Netbeans does not accept it. Is there any tutorial or full example online to follow?

Comment: I think your problem is very simple to solve but like this, it is almost impossible. I'd suggest getting some help from people around you if you have any. It must be related either with Netbeans setup or the dependencies are messed up.

Comment: I followed the instruction on the website exactly. First I created a maven project using the command:

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=info.magnolia.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=magnolia-module-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE

Then I pasted the the code above and the constructor gives me errors, both in netbeans and in eclipse. I am sure if you do the same you will get the same error because I tried it 5 times from scratch. there is a simple but critical piece of information missing from the guides.